# How to run multiple file .sql with mysql?

Tags: mysql, shell

I tried to run this command in shell:

> ```
> mysql> source /path/*.sql
> ```

But I did not have any results.
Do you have any suggestions what is wrong?

Comment: Refer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/405897/how-can-i-import-multiple-sql-files-into-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use Bash like this:

```
cat *.sql | mysql
```

or

```
cat script*.sql | mysql -u root -pmypassword  yourdatabase
```

Comment: Just an addendum, this works as long as the statements are terminated by `;`

Comment: i tried but the result on shell is this:

mysql> cat *.sql | mysql
    ->

and than i cannot do anything on file in my folder /path/to/folder/files.sql

Comment: the second one is correct in my case :) thank you so much